# Importing pandas (and other modules) in Flask on EC2 ubuntu gives an error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pandas, flask

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS EC2 instance (I have installed apache, java etc.) and have a working version of Anaconda/Python.

I have also setup flask (running behind apache) and set up a virtual host. I have the following directory set-up for flask:

[image]

My ***init**.py* file is very simple:

```
from __future__ import division

import string
import datetime
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import abort

#import pandas as pd
#import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def hello():
    return "test6"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then, after running *python **init**.py*, when I got to my EC2 instance public address everything is fine and I get the message 'test6' as expected.

Now I uncomment either *pandas* or *requests*, everything server/flask side runs fine with:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

When I run:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

I get back what I expect (i.e. 'test6').

BUT when I navigate to the same EC2 public URL I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@mywebsite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com Port 80
```

Does anyone know what is happening? I am just importing two modules that I am able to import from the command line version of python (and also the whole setup works fine locally on my mac).

Maybe its running out of memory since its small instance?

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Just looking at the apache server logs (error.log):

```
[Sun Nov 03 21:48:56 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 03 21:49:51 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 03 21:49:52 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sun Nov 03 21:49:52 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sun Nov 03 21:49:52 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=6874): Target WSGI script '/var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=6874): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi'.
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]   File "/var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]     from app import app as application
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]   File "/var/www/microblog/app/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]     import pandas as pd
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ImportError: No module named pandas
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=6873): Target WSGI script '/var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=6873): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi'.
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]   File "/var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]     from app import app as application
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]   File "/var/www/microblog/app/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx]     import pandas as pd
[Sun Nov 03 21:50:03 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Comment: Can you enable the debugger to get a stack trace? Just pass `debug = True` as an argument to `app.run()`.

Comment: Just did that - seems like no issues flask side - I have a feeling its something to do with 'sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi' - just looking at the apache server logs and trying to figure it out...Just pasted log into question

Comment: The log is pretty clear, you don't have `pandas`.

Comment: I dont think thats quite right - I do have Pandas (because I installed Anaconda) but Apache is not pointing to the right python version & modules...pls defo add the resolution to you your book (once I have found solution) - I am looking forward to your book!

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am facing the same error. I have pandas.